# Why socketIO call too much connections?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I created my Socket server with Express, SocketIO and Redis

`server.js`

```
var app    = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io     = require('socket.io')(server);
var redis  = require('redis');

server.listen(8890, function (e) {
    console.log(e);
});
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log("new client connected");
    var redisClient = redis.createClient();
    redisClient.subscribe('message');

    redisClient.on("message", function(channel, message) {
        console.log("mew message in queue "+ message + "channel");
        socket.emit(channel, message);
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        redisClient.quit();
    });

    socket.on('connect_error', function() {
        redisClient.quit();
    });
});
```

From command line, I run `node server.js`. Its worked.

I also created a html file to connect to that server.
From Browser Console, I run `io.connect('http://localhost:8890')`. I got as the result
[image]

As I see, too much connections (requests).
What happens? What wrong from my code?

Comment: These are due to polling in socket.io.

Comment: With recent versions of socket.io, it will sometimes get stuck polling over and over if you have mismatched client and server versions of socket.io.  How are you loading the client-side socket.io.js file?  Are you loading it directly from your socket.io server (where it will be guaranteed to be the correct version) or are you loading it statically from somewhere else?  Please show us your client-side code.

Comment: @jfriend00 for client, I loaded from CDN at https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.3.4.js
and for server, I use SocketIO version 2.0.4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have mismatched client and server versions causing the initial connection to fail and the older client is dumb enough to just keep trying over and over again.  If you are using 2.0.4 on the server, then you must use that version for the client too.  If you serve the client version directly from your server with:

```
<script src="http://localhost:8890/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

Then, the socket.io server will automatically give you the right client version.

Or, you can manually link to the right version on your CDN such as `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.4/socket.io.js`.  But client and server versions MUST match.

The advantage of getting the client directly from your own server is that anytime you update your server version of socket.io, the client version will automatically be upgraded for you and kept in perfect sync since the matching client version is built into the server version.

Comment: It helped me a lot. Thank you so much